# Draggable element runs click function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, click, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a draggable element inside my jQuery code and the same element has a click function. Everything works well, but when I drag the element, it runs the click function too. What can I do to prevent this?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="clickable"></div>
  <div id="content">A!</div>
</div>
```

The div with the class "container" is draggable and `.clickable` has a `click` function to toggle the div with the id `content`.

Comment: Could you post your code and HTML. You'll probably need to restructure the HTML.

Comment: I've just edited my post.

Comment: You could use `mousedown` and `mouseup` perhaps. What you're asking for is tricky, you might have to calculate the time in between the two and do click if it's below a certain limit and drag if it's above that limit, but that's prone to lots of bugs and such. That or just have an area of the div that is draggable and another part clickable

Comment: You can add a class on drag start and remove it on drag stop, in you click function check if the element have a class and if so, exit the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in my comment you can add a class to the element (eg `dragging`) when you start dragging in the [`start`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start) function of the draggable, than check in the click handler if the element (or the parent of it in your case) have to class or alternatively fire the function.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.container').draggable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass('dragging');
        }
    });

    $('.clickable').click(function (event) {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('dragging')) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('dragging');
        } else {
            //alert("real click");
            $("#content").toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Maybe there are alternatives to this, but is the only solution that I used.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/N3bKb/

Docs:

- http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/
- http://api.jquery.com/addClass/
- http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/